# Increase a Test Class code

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

i have an issue, i want to increase in my test class this code:

```
 if(!String.isBlank(account.A_Field_Picklist__c) &&
 !ClassOfCostants.NotValutable.equalsIgnoreCase(account.A_Field_Picklist__c) )
```

The condition over it is an if and it's blue, i tried this test method:

```
static testMethod void test() {

    Test.startTest();

    Account a= new Account();

    a.A_Field_Picklist__c= ' ';
    a.A_Field_Picklist__c= 'A VALUE';

    insert(a);

    Test.stopTest();

    }
```

But it didn't work. The code coverage is at 1%.
Thnaks In advance to everyone that will reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this approach.

First insert the record with blank and next, update the same record with some valid data.

```
static testMethod void test() {
    Test.startTest();
    Account a= new Account();
    a.A_Field_Picklist__c= '';
    insert(a);

    Account aObj = [SELECT A_Field_Picklist__c FROM Account WHERE Id=:a.Id];

    aObj.A_Field_Picklist__c= 'A VALUE';
    update aObj;   
    System.assertEquals (....);
    Test.stopTest();

}
```